# Emulating a C++ enum class C++ in C

Tags: c, enum

I am trying to emulate a C++ enum class in C and the code works as I expect. I used this code as indicated on
[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflo_3.com/questions/2124339/c-preprocessor-va-args-number-of-arguments).

```
// .................................................... JOIN
#define JOIN(id,_1) id ## _1
// .................................................... CONCAT
#define CONCAT(id,_1) JOIN(id,_1)

#ifdef _MSC_VER // Microsoft compilers

#   define GET_ARG_COUNT(...)  INTERNAL_EidPAND_ARGS_PRIVATE(INTERNAL_ARGS_AUGMENTER(__VA_ARGS__))

#   define INTERNAL_ARGS_AUGMENTER(...) unused, __VA_ARGS__
#   define INTERNAL_EidPAND(id) id
#   define INTERNAL_EidPAND_ARGS_PRIVATE(...) INTERNAL_EidPAND(INTERNAL_GET_ARG_COUNT_PRIVATE(__VA_ARGS__, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0))
#   define INTERNAL_GET_ARG_COUNT_PRIVATE(_1_, _2_, _3_, _4_, _5_, _6_, _7_, _8_, _9_, _10_, _11_, _12_, _13_, _14_, _15_, _16_, _17_, _18_, _19_, _20_, _21_, _22_, _23_, _24_, _25_, _26_, _27_, _28_, _29_, _30_, _31_, _32_, _33_, _34_, _35_, _36, _37, _38, _39, _40, _41, _42, _43, _44, _45, _46, _47, _48, _49, _50, _51, _52, _53, _54, _55, _56, _57, _58, _59, _60, _61, _62, _63, _64, _65, _66, _67, _68, _69, _70, count, ...) count

#else // Non-Microsoft compilers

#   define GET_ARG_COUNT(...) INTERNAL_GET_ARG_COUNT_PRIVATE(0, ## __VA_ARGS__, 70, 69, 68, 67, 66, 65, 64, 63, 62, 61, 60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)
#   define INTERNAL_GET_ARG_COUNT_PRIVATE(_0, _1_, _2_, _3_, _4_, _5_, _6_, _7_, _8_, _9_, _10_, _11_, _12_, _13_, _14_, _15_, _16_, _17_, _18_, _19_, _20_, _21_, _22_, _23_, _24_, _25_, _26_, _27_, _28_, _29_, _30_, _31_, _32_, _33_, _34_, _35_, _36, _37, _38, _39, _40, _41, _42, _43, _44, _45, _46, _47, _48, _49, _50, _51, _52, _53, _54, _55, _56, _57, _58, _59, _60, _61, _62, _63, _64, _65, _66, _67, _68, _69, _70, count, ...) count

#endif

#define OVERLOAD    CONCAT
#define ARG         GET_ARG_COUNT
```

so I reproduced the sequence in this way:

```
// EnumClass1   enum { }
// EnumClass2   enum id { } ;
#define EnumClass2(id,_1)\
    enum id##_e { id##_##_1 }

#define EnumClass3(id,_1,_2)\
     enum id##_e { id##_##_1 , id##_##_2 }

#define EnumClass4(id,_1,_2,_3)\
    enum id##_e { id##_##_1 , id##_##_2 , id##_##_3 }

#define EnumClass5(id,_1,_2,_3,_4)\
    enum id##_e { id##_##_1 , id##_##_2 , id##_##_3 , id##_##_4 }    

#define EnumClass6(id,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5)\
    enum id##_e { id##_##_1 , id##_##_2 , id##_##_3 , id##_##_4 , id##_##_5 } 

#define EnumClass7(id,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6)\
    enum id##_e { id##_##_1 , id##_##_2 , id##_##_3 , id##_##_4 , id##_##_5 , id##_##_6 } 

#define EnumClass8(id,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7)\
    enum id##_e { id##_##_1 , id##_##_2 , id##_##_3 , id##_##_4 , id##_##_5 , id##_##_6 , id##_##_7 }
```

and so on, with significant enum the repetition of code becomes abnormal:

```
#define EnumClass(...)  OVERLOAD ( EnumClass  , ARG(__VA_ARGS__) ) ( __VA_ARGS__ )
```

This is the last part of the code and works with Visual Studio and gcc:

```
int main(void)
{
    EnumClass(sender
       ,lexer=100
       ,parser

   ) a ;

   a=sender_parser ;

   printf ( "\n%d\n",a ) ;

   return 0 ;
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to avoid continuous repetitions of macros?

Other related questions:

- [How to emulate strongly typed enum in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903625/how-to-emulate-strongly-typed-enum-in-c)
- [Does “enum class” exist in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52657232/does-enum-class-exist-in-c)

After many attempts I have found this solution:

```
#define EnumClass1(ID,X1      )  ID##_##X1 
#define EnumClass2(ID,X1,...  )  ID##_##X1 ,  OVERLOAD ( EnumClass  , ARG(__VA_ARGS__) ) ( ID,__VA_ARGS__ )
...
#define EnumClass64(ID,X1,... )  ID##_##X1 ,  OVERLOAD ( EnumClass  , ARG(__VA_ARGS__) ) ( ID,__VA_ARGS__ )
```

Comment: Where is EnumClass(sender, lexer, parser) declared or defined?

Comment: first arg is ID, other is member of enum : enum Class sender { lexer,parser } ; in C++, here the main macro code #define EnumClass(...) , so i obtain sender_lexer and son on.